# function prototype with multiple parameters including void

Tags: void-pointers, function-prototypes

I have a piece of software in which there is a function ie:

`void function_name(structure_t *param1, void *param2){code....}`

I am trying to create a function prototype for this function so it can be linked to another function that occurs before it. I have tried the below line with no success, it does not want to compile.

`void function_name(structure_t, void);`

I have this line below the associated structure but my guess is the problem is related to the void. The function itself takes the void *param2, which to be honest, confuses me but it works.

The compiler gives the error message: "'void' must be the only parameter"

Comment: What language are you working in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Function declaration is missing the * to define the arguments as pointers!

```
void function_name(structure_t *, void *);
```

Comment: thanks, that did resolve the problem with the function prototype but now it is saying that the two types do not match. I typed them exactly as they are in the code, any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: would really need the code for that... but my guess would be that it's not using the same structure_t in the declaration as in the definition.